# In Python `unittest`, how can I return a value after exception/warning happened in try - except?

Tags: python, unit-testing, warnings, try-except

Here is my codes.

```
import unittest
import warnings

def function_that_raises_CustomWarning():
    warnings.warn("warning")
    return True

class test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        is_this_True = False
        is_CustomWarning_raised = False

        try:
            is_this_True = function_that_raises_CustomWarning()
        except Warning:
            is_CustomWarning_raised = True

        self.assertTrue(is_this_True)
        self.assertTrue(is_CustomWarning_raised)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

`is_this_True` in `self.assertTrue(is_this_True)` is `False`, hence failed the test.

What I want is for `is_this_True` in `self.assertTrue(is_this_True)` to be `True`. However, the return value is not "captured" since the value is returned **after** a warning is raised in `function_that_raises_CustomWarning()`.

How can I return the value in `function_that_raises_CustomWarning()` but also "captured" the warning in `except`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code with 3.6 on Windows, the failure is with `self.assertTrue(is_CustomWarning_raised)`.  By default, a warning is not an exception and cannot be caught with `except:`.  The solution is to use `assertWarns` or `assertWarnsRegex`.  I used the latter to show how it might be used to add an extra test.

```
import unittest
import warnings

def function_that_raises_CustomWarning():
    warnings.warn("my warning")
    return True

class test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        is_this_True = False

        with self.assertWarnsRegex(Warning, 'my warning'):
            is_this_True = function_that_raises_CustomWarning()
        self.assertTrue(is_this_True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Did know that I can assert based on warning raised as well. In my experience `except` does work with `Warning` as well. In this case I prefer to use `self.assertWarns(MoreSpecificWarning)` instead, since I do not want to deal with regex.

Comment: Warnings should not be catchable exceptions unless one starts python with `-W error` https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W or add a warning filter with the `'error'` action https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings.  Perhaps the systems you use have 'error' turned on somehow in a startup script.  Using assertWarns should work everywhere.